# Maximising and minimising the sum of reciprocals of a set with distinct natural numbers summing to $2024$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

$2024$ is right around the corner. And I have been stumped by the following problem:

Consider a set $S$ of distinct natural numbers such that $\sum_{s \in S} s = 2024$.

Find the minimum and maximum possible values of $\sum_{s\in S} \frac{1}{s}$ and also find the number of elements of $S$ in each case.

I asked a somewhat similar problem earlier which involved maximizing the product of elements of some set with similar conditions, but I don't think I've been able to make any progress even with that background question.

Source: This question was proposed to me by my friend.

**My work**:

I could only think of the AM-HM inequality wherefrom we know that if $n$ is the number of elements in $S$ then

$$\frac{2024}{n} \geq \frac{n}{\sum_{s\in S} \frac{1}{s}}$$

But that is not even slightly helpful here, since it offers only a minimum for the desired sum in terms of the cardinality of $S$, and that minimum isn't even correct since it requires for all elements of $S$ to be equal which isn't allowed.

Is it possible to solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to the some motivation in comments it can be proved that the minimising set is $S=\{2024\}$.

From the aforementioned inequality, it holds that:

$$\sum_{s \in S} \frac{1}{s} \geq \frac{n^2}{2024}$$.

For $n \geq 2$, $\sum_{s \in S} \frac{1}{s} > \frac{1}{506}$.

But at $n=1$, $S=\{2024\}$ and $\frac{1}{506} > \frac{1}{2024}$.

So the minimizing set is $S=\{2024\}$.

Comment: I suggest:  solve the problem for numbers smaller than $2024$. That should tell you a lot about the nature of the solutions (though, for the minimum, I can't imagine that anything beats the singleton $2024$).

Comment: I thought of the same for the minimum, although I don't have any way to argue for that.

Comment: That minimum is attained on the singleton should provable by just considering two parts, and I think that inequality will be easy to deal with.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to prove that the minimising set is $\{2024\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the minimum value you could get is for the set $S=\{2024\}$. 
We can now check if this is correct using proof similiar to induction (not induction since cardinality of $S$ has an upper bound). I'll denote $n=|S|$. 
Suppose $n=2$ and $S=\{k_1,k_2\}$. We have to prove that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2024}< \frac{1}{k_1}+\frac{1}{k_2}$. Since for $k_1\ne 2024$ (which keep in mind it has to be if we want $S$ to have two elements, both being from $\mathbb{N}$) we have $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2024}<\frac{1}{k_1}$, then obviously $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2024}<\frac{1}{k_1}<\frac{1}{k_1}+\frac{1}{k_2}$. So the statement holds for all $S$, such that $|S|=2$.
Now, let's suppose that statement is true for some set $S=\{k_1,\dots,k_n\}$, $|S|=n$. Meaning $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2024}< \frac{1}{k_1}+\dots+\frac{1}{k_n}$
Now let's check if it is true for $S=\{k_1,\dots,k_n,k_{n+1}\}$, $|S|=n+1$. From $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2024}< \frac{1}{k_1}+\dots+\frac{1}{k_n}<\frac{1}{k_1}+\dots+\frac{1}{k_n}+\frac{1}{k_{n+1}}$ we conclude that the $S={2024}$ is the set that will give you the minimum value.

Now for the maximum I'll give you a rough idea, you can do the proof as an exercise, it shouldn't be hard. First add $1$ to $S$, then $2,3,\dots$ until you get to the number, let's denote it as $l$ such that $1+2+\dots (l-1)+l>2024$ and $1+2+\dots+(l-1)<2024$. Now $S=\{1,2,3,\dots,l-1\}$. The last element to add will be $2024-(1+2+\dots+(l-1))$.
If my calculations are correct then you should get $S=\{1,2,\dots,61,62,71\}$ and $\displaystyle \sum_{s\in S}\frac{1}{s}=4.73$.

Comment: Please someone check if I'm allowed to prove the first statement in the way that I did.

Comment: I think that maximum is correct. I really only needed the maximum now. Thanks.

Comment: I confirmed the maximum via integer linear programming.

Answer (score -1):

The minimum is obviously 1/2024.

To get a large number, you would start by adding 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + … Eventually you have to stop. Just guessing numbers, you might add 1/53 and have 97 left; you can’t add 1/54 and 1/43 because that would be a duplicate, so you add 1/97.

Adding 1/54 + 1/96 instead of 1/53 + 1/97 would be smaller, so the original procedure gives the maximum result: Add 1/k for k = 1, 2, 3, … as long as 2k+1 is >= the remaining number. Then add 1 divided by the remaining number.

Comment: I think you are wrong. I could guess the set $S = \{1,2,3,\dots, 55, 57, 58,\dots,64\}$ with consecutive integers from $1$ to $64$ excluding $56$ and it has a larger value at $4.7$ whereas your scheme gives $4.5$. However I can not find if it is the maximising set.